# Where is the error // why doesn't it work? (Java Chat program)

Tags: java, udp, chat

I wanted to write a UDP java chat program where I can send and receive messages to and from another person using this program. I figured out socket programming by my own (google search etc.), so I don't completely understand every single part. The basic idea is to read a random IP you want to chat with as a String, converting it into an IP and starting two threads, one for sending messages from port A and one for receiving messages at port B (the threads are used for being both able to send and recieve messages at the same time). Every thread has it's own class. So far, so good. Now both classes have the method run which are both in a big try-catch block. At the two catch blocks, I added several error messages, first "Test123" and then "Test456" so I can understand what happens when. When compiling the code, I can type in the IP (I tried localhost for testing). But when I type in the message, I should recieve the message "chat partner sent: ", but instead I don't get anything. Now both threads are in an infinite loop, so when I force the program to terminate (by pressing Ctrl+C (I run the .class via command)), I get the error message "Test123" before the program terminates. My questions are: Why don't I receive any message and why does the program throw "Test123" when I force the program to terminate? Where are my errors?
Thanks in advance for helping. Here's the code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class chat {
    static InetAddress IP;
    static int sPort=11111;
    static int rPort=11112;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Zu welcher IP soll verbunden werden?");//"which IP do you want to connect with?"
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String IPraw=sc.next(); //type in the IP address as String
        IP=InetAddress.getByName(IPraw); //converting the String into real IP address
        Thread sender = new sender();
        sender.start(); //start the sending thread
        Thread receiver = new receiver();
        receiver.start(); //start the receiving thread
    }
}
class sender extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        Scanner scantext = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            DatagramSocket Socket = new DatagramSocket();
            while(true){
                String TextSend = scantext.next();
                sendData = TextSend.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, chat.IP, chat.rPort);
                Socket.send(out);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Test123");
        }
    }
}

class receiver extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        try{
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            while(true){
                DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length, chat.IP, chat.sPort);
                socket.receive(in);
                String message = new String(in.getData());
                System.out.println("Chatpartner sagt: " + message);//"partner said <message>"           
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Test456");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't catch exceptions and print next-to-useless messages. Use `e.printStackTrace()` instead.

Comment: Quick side-note, if you want a chat-application you probably don't want to use UDP. The TCP protocol ensures arrival of the packets, but UDP ignores packet distortion.

Comment: You will get way more information about your errors if you do what hexafraction says. Once you do that, post the exception stack trace here and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: You may need another aproach, writing a server that can get connections, and then clients that can connect to that server.

Comment: When I put the try-catch block as comment, I get errors when compiling:
chat.java:24: error: unreported exception SocketException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   DatagramSocket Socket = new DatagramSocket();
                           ^
chat.java:29: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Socket.send(out);
          ^
2 errors

Comment: @Exabytez Then unless you have a very good reason otherwise, declare those exceptions to be thrown. Catching the exceptions and printing out `"TestXXX"` is preventing you from seeing one of the most helpful things you can have while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

the sender thread is wating for you to insert some data on System.in (just type something).
It is blocked here, on this line:  String TextSend = scantext.next();

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your application does not work because you are sending the data to different ports.

```
static int sPort=11111;
static int rPort=11112;
```

You need to send it to the same port (and in case of sending it to your own computer, you need to specify either your `local ip-address`, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`).

As for your first question

```
Why don't I receive any message
```

Are you connecting to `127.0.0.1`? What exactly are your parameters?

As for your second question

```
why does the program throw "Test123" when I force the program to terminate?
```

because at that very moment you break the while-loop

```
try{
    DatagramSocket Socket = new DatagramSocket();
    while(true){
        String TextSend = scantext.next();
        sendData = TextSend.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, chat.IP, chat.rPort);
        Socket.send(out);
    }
}
```

Terminating the application like that results in an exception.

Comment: I both tried typing in localhost and 127.0.0.1, but no matter how many messages I type in afterwards, I don't receive any of those messages.

Comment: Yes I have, but no result. I printed sendData after scanning in the text, no matter what I type, I get some combination, always beginning with [B@ and going on with some random letters.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending on one port, and receiving on another. If your intention is for this code to send and receive its own message, those ports will need to be the same.  If your intention is to actually chat with someone else (even with yourself on localhost), the other chat would have to receive on your send port and send on your receive port.

Also, what hexafraction said:

> Don't catch exceptions and print next-to-useless messages. Use e.printStackTrace() instead.

That's where your error went, you caught it and printed your message instead

Comment: I do not have the reputation to comment on bas' answer, but what you are seeing is the result of trying to print a byte array as a string.  [B denotes a byte array. Print TextSent instead and you should see the  correct text

Comment: Now I sent the message to the receiving port and put in e.printStackTrace() at the catch block, this is what I got:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null address || null buffer
Do you guys have any clue?